# Django Channels: chan you check the number of sockets inside a room/channel_layer

Tags: django-channels

Same as the question itself. How can you check the number of live sockets inside a room or a channel_layer if you are using django channels?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly from the generic channel layer api, if you'r using Redis you could look into the Redis api and check how many subscriptions are open.

this could be done using this api:

https://redis.io/commands/client-list

(this might be quite slow and costly if you have lots of open connections to your redis cluster)

You will need to convert the group name into the group key in the same way the redis layer is doing this see here:

https://github.com/django/channels_redis/blob/master/channels_redis/core.py#L582